# Return dynamic cast Activity

Tags: java, android, casting

I'm working on a testing lib for Android.

What I want to do is to create a method that creates an activity from it class name and return the activity instance.

For example, I receive the class name for `SampleActivity` and this class as an activity extends android's `Activity` class. Then what I need to return is an instance of `SampleActivity`

Try and catch removed for clarity.

This is what I have by now

```
public static Class<? extends Activity> createActivity(String activityName){

    Class<? extends Activity> clazz = null;
    Class<? extends Activity> activity = null;

    clazz = (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(activityName);
    activity = clazz.newInstance(); // incompatible type

    return activity;
}
```

Comment: Usually activity instantiation is performed by OS. What you need manual instantiation for?

Comment: Testing with Robolectric

Comment: Do you want the return type as class or an object of the class i.e. Activity ?

Comment: Shouldn't your `activity` variable be declared as `Activity` (not `Class`)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your activity variable to be of type Activity and not Class.

You should also change the method declaration something like:

```
public <T extends Activity> T createActivity(String className)
```

If you only know the class as a String this is about the best you can do and a consumer will only know the returned object as an Activity. It will need to cast it if it wants a more specific type.  Seeing as you only seem to have the class name as a string how will your calling code even know the type to cast to anyway.

Now if you actually had the class type at compile time you could define the method like this:

```
public <T extends Activity> createActivity(Class<T> clazz){
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

But I was under the impression that you do not have the concrete class at compile time.

Comment: return type of the `createActivity` method should be changed as well

Comment: If I return `Activity` type I will have to cast it outside, And that's not an option (unless there is no other way). I want to return the activity defined, i.e. `SampleActivity` where obviously `SampleActivity` extends `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I am understanding correctly this is what you need to do:

```
public static Activity createActivity(String activityName)
{
    Class<? extends Activity> c = (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(activityName);
    Activity activity = c.newInstance();
    return activity;
}
```

You can use this class as follows:

```
SampleActivity sampleActivity = (SampleActivity) createActivity("com.abc.SampleActivity");
```

**OR**

If you want to return the `Class` then use

```
public static Class<? extends Activity> createActivity(String activityName)
{
    Class<? extends Activity> clazz = null;
    Class<? extends Activity> activity = null;

    clazz = (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(activityName);
    activity = clazz.newInstance(); 
    return activity.class;
}
```

Make sure the `activityName` is the **fully qualified name of the class** and also the class represented by `activityName` should be a subclass of `Activity`.

Comment: I want to return a SampleActivity instance. SampleActivity extends Activity.